# Pyomo Constraint Block in Abstract Model

Tags: python-3.x, model, block, abstract, pyomo

For a better structure of my Constraints, I want to summarize multiple constraints into a block, so that a don't have to scroll through a long list of separate functions representing my constraints.

My problem is that I'm using an Abstract model and don't know how to define that Block for a set that has not been initialized yet

```
M.s = pe.Set(dimen=1)

M.chp_minPower = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_maxPower = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_posGrad = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_negGrad = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_k = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_c = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_f1 = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.chp_f2 = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)
M.gasCost = pe.Param(within=pe.Reals,mutable=True)

M.chpOn = pe.Var(M.s, within=pe.Binary)
M.chpSwitchON = pe.Var(M.s,within=pe.Binary)
M.chpPel = pe.Var(M.s,within=pe.NonNegativeReals)
M.chpPth = pe.Var(M.s, within=pe.NonNegativeReals)
M.chpQGas = pe.Var(M.s, within=pe.NonNegativeReals)

def chp_block_rule1(nb,i):
    #Constraints
    nb.chpPelMax = pe.Constraint(expr=M.chpPel[i] <= M.chp_maxPower * M.chpOn[i])
    nb.chpPelMin = pe.Constraint(expr=M.chpPel[i] >= M.chp_minPower * M.chpOn[i])
    #b.sellBin = pe.Constraint(expr=b.sell[i]/M.maxSell <= M.sellBin[i]
    nb.chpCogen = pe.Constraint(expr=M.chpPth[i] == M.chp_f1 * M.chpPel[i] + M.chp_f2 * M.chpOn[i])
    nb.chpConsumption = pe.Constraint(expr=M.chpQGas[i] == M.chp_c * M.chpOn[i] + M.chp_k + M.chpPel[i])
M.chp_block = pe.Block(M.s, rule=chp_block_rule1)
```

> ValueError: Error retrieving component chpPel[1]: The component has
>   not been constructed.

Does anybody know how to work with blocks in Abstract models?

Comment: What version of Pyomo are you using? When I run your code it seems to work fine with no modifications.

Comment: I'm using Pyomo 5.6.4. The error occurs when the abstract Model is being instanciated with M.create_instance(data)

Comment: Could you try updating to Pyomo 5.6.7? Also could you post an example of the data that you're sending to the `create_instance` method?

Comment: I updated to Pyomo 5.6.7 but the error still arises. The data looks like this: `s = {None:[x for x in range(1,193)]}  ;         data = {None:{'s':s}}     ;     data[None].update({'chp_minPower':{None:5}})`

Comment: If you're programmatically loading the data from Python dictionaries then why are you choosing to use an `AbstractModel` instead of a `ConcreteModel`?

Comment: I'm using `AbstractModel` because I want to use two instances of the same Model that basically differ in the length of set s

Comment: (I'm not an authority as @BethanyNicholson but I do see advantages in using AbstractModels even when using raw dictionaries, namely the fact that one day you might want to instantiate the same model from a file or whatever other input format).
If you could add the way `data` is generated to the question it would help debugging. My guess is that for some reason you're not setting `chpPel[1]` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure but I guess `expr` tries to actually evaluate the expression, and because `chpPel` is a variable (thus has no value) it breaks.

In order to delay the evaluation of the expression (i.e. pass the expression into the solver as symbolic), you can use `rule` instead of `expr`.
As you probably know `rule` takes a function. If the expression is short enough, you can use a lambda function.

```py
nb.chpPelMax = pe.Constraint(rule=lambda M: M.chpPel[i] <= M.chp_maxPower * M.chpOn[i])
```

Side note: you can just use `list(range(...))` instead of the list comprehension.